# If $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function on the unit interval, what is the distribution of $f(\mathcal{U})$? Prove it.

Tags: uniform-distribution

$\mathcal{U}$ is distributed uniformly on the interval $[0,1]$. If $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function on the unit interval, what is the distribution of $f(\mathcal{U})$? Prove it.

Well if $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function on the unit interval, then $f'(x)>0$ on $[0,1]$. But I don't know where to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given: $f:[0,1] \to \mathbf{R}$ strictly increasing and $U$ uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$.

$U$ uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ means: $\forall_{x \in [0,1]}: P(U \le x) = x$.  We say that U's cumulative distribution function is $x \mapsto x$.

Let's now look at the cumulative distribution function of $f(U)$:
$\forall_{x \in \mathbf{R}}: P(f(U) \le x) = P(f(U) \le x_{f}) \stackrel{(*)}{=} P(U \le f^{-1}(x_{f})) \stackrel{(**)}{=} f^{-1}(x_{f})$, where $x_{f}=\sup\{y \in f([0,1]) | y \le x\}$, $(*)$ holds for strictly increasing $f$ (which also means that $f$ is invertible), and $(**)$ follows from $U$ being uniformly distributed.

Thus $f(U)$'s cumulative distribution function is $x \mapsto f^{-1}(x_f)$.

Comment: So if $f$ is strictly decreasing then the proof is the same?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown: I've now fixed the mistake you uncovered. You'll notice that $f$ is no longer assumed to be a bijection on the unit interval, and possible discontinuities are taken into account now as well. If $f$ is instead strictly decreasing, then $P(f(U) \le x_{f}) = P(U \ge f^{-1}(x_{f})) = 1 - P(U \le f^{-1}(x_{f})) = 1 - f^{-1}(x_{f})$.

Comment: Perfect. That's what I thought. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $f(\mathcal U) \le f(x)$ iff $\mathcal U \le  x$ for $0 \le x \le 1$.

Comment: (1) How did you arrive to this? (2) How does this tell me what the distribution?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/631790)

Comment: @Xoque55  Hints are preferred to complete answers for questions that are likely to be homework.

Comment: (1) that's essentially what "strictly increasing" means. (2) it tells you the cumulative distribution function (at least for those $y$ that are values of $f$).

Comment: So the cummulative distribution of the function will be $x$ and the density function will be $1$? So how would I formally prove this?

Comment: No, that's the cumulative distribution function and density of $\mathcal U$.

Comment: Ok I am confused. Your hint doesn't seem to be helping. How do I need to think of the question to come up with a claim and then how should I prove the claim true? I don't want a completely spelled out proof but I do want a sense of what has to be done